# Context menu isn't opened using Safari WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webautomation, safaridriver

Unable to open context menu in Safari browser using SafariDriver Selenium. Getting following exceptions:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unknown command:
>   {"id":"az1mvyq9x4ly","name":"mouseMoveTo","parameters":
>   {"element":":wdc:1463726481487"}} (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 5 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:06:42'
>   System info: host: 'RVSKCH19LT', ip: '192.168.10.30', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_11'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver
>   Capabilities [{browserName=safari, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, version=5.1.7, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, platform=WINDOWS, secureSsl=true}]
>   Session ID: null

Answer (score 0):

```
try this code to resolve your issue.  

WebElement obj = driver.findelement(by.xpath(""));     
    Action act = new Action(driver);
    act.contextClick(obj).perform();

    share your code review.
```

Answer (score 0):

Actions/Interactions API is not implemented with SafariDriver yet.
Please try with the following JavaScript solution:

```
String script = "var element = document.querySelector('SOME_CSS_SELECTOR');var e = element.ownerDocument.createEvent(\"MouseEvents\"); e.initMouseEvent(\"contextmenu\", true, true, element.ownerDocument.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false,2, null); element.dispatchEvent(e);";
driver.executeScript(script);
```

Replace SOME_CSS_SELECTOR with the css selector of the element where you want the right click.